# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'conferID'

Tags: c#, sql-server

Am trying to retrieve specific dates of a conference from the database to display on a web page.  Read the ConferenceID as shown here:

```
conferID = reader["ConferenceID"].ToString();
```

I would like the page to display only dates from ConferenceID='3', but I was also getting dates from ConferenceID='1' and ConferenceID='2' when I removed (ConferenceID = conferID) from codes below.  However, if I added (ConferenceID = conferID) back to the codes, the page broke.  If I put these codes in SQL to test and change (ConferenceID=conferID) to (ConferenceID='3'), it worked.  I am lost right now.  Any help is appreciated.

```
SqlCommand GetDates = new SqlCommand(@"
WITH x AS (
             select MAX(ConferenceID) as ConferenceID, row_number() over(order by D.Dates) as SN, D.Dates 
             from Conference as T 
                  inner join master..spt_values as N 
                  on N.number between 0 and datediff(day, T.ConferenceBeginDate, T.ConferenceEndDate) 
                  cross apply (select dateadd(day, N.number, T.ConferenceBeginDate)) as D(Dates) 
                  where N.type ='P' AND (ConferenceID = conferID) group by ConferenceID, D.Dates
                  )
SELECT ConferenceID, SN, Dates
FROM x
WHERE SN <> (Select MAX(SN) from x) AND (ConferenceID = conferID)
GROUP BY ConferenceID, SN, Dates", conn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use sql parameters.

```
SqlCommand GetDates = new SqlCommand(@"
WITH x AS (
             select MAX(ConferenceID) as ConferenceID, row_number() over(order by D.Dates) as SN, D.Dates 
             from Conference as T 
                  inner join master..spt_values as N 
                  on N.number between 0 and datediff(day, T.ConferenceBeginDate, T.ConferenceEndDate) 
                  cross apply (select dateadd(day, N.number, T.ConferenceBeginDate)) as D(Dates) 
                  where N.type ='P' AND (ConferenceID = @conferId) group by ConferenceID, D.Dates
                  )
SELECT ConferenceID, SN, Dates
FROM x
WHERE SN <> (Select MAX(SN) from x) AND (ConferenceID = @conferId)
GROUP BY ConferenceID, SN, Dates", conn);

GetDates.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conferId", conferId);
```

The issue here is that you are trying to reference a field that does not exist. I assume you're trying to reference a string that is available and therefore you must add it as a named parameter, then assign it via this.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add conferID as a `Parameter`. Try this

```
SqlCommand GetDates = new SqlCommand(@"
WITH x AS (
             select MAX(ConferenceID) as ConferenceID, row_number() over(order by D.Dates) as SN, D.Dates 
             from Conference as T 
                  inner join master..spt_values as N 
                  on N.number between 0 and datediff(day, T.ConferenceBeginDate, T.ConferenceEndDate) 
                  cross apply (select dateadd(day, N.number, T.ConferenceBeginDate)) as D(Dates) 
                  where N.type ='P' AND (ConferenceID = @ConferenceID) group by ConferenceID, D.Dates
                  )
SELECT ConferenceID, SN, Dates
FROM x
WHERE SN <> (Select MAX(SN) from x) AND (ConferenceID = @ConferenceID)
GROUP BY ConferenceID, SN, Dates", conn);

GetDates.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ConferenceID", conferID));
```

Comment: you're right about adding a parameter but I think the last statement `GetDates.Parameter...("ConferenceID") should be ("@ConferenceID").  I am marking your answer as useful.  Thanks!